# SWIFT: NSData contentsOfUrl returns nil from valid URL

Tags: swift2, nsdata, nsurl

I have an URL (NOT A path or a string): `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/50558DAA-7082-4BB0-AB0C-F7BA0DC483E5/tmp/yFFaofWcIWln-SCVideo-Merged.mp4`

When I use `NSData(contentsOfUrl: url)` i get `nil`.

I have tried same code with an asset from library URL without any problems.

Is there a difference in the two URLS?
Anybody knows how to extract NSData from the above URL?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Seems like there was a problem with the actual file, for some reason it contained only audio and no video. Needs further investigating.
Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, it was the actual data in the URL that was missing... So that is why it returned nil.

Thanks guys for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the URL?
There are many ways to create a URL. You should use `init(fileURLWithPath path: String)` when create the NSURL with a file path.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the path in the URL is correct or not which could be a reason for `contentsOfUrl` returning `nil`.

However, what you are trying can easily be achieved like this:

```
let filePath = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/50558DAA-7082-4BB0-AB0C-F7BA0DC483E5/tmp/yFFaofWcIWln-SCVideo-Merged.mp4"
let data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(filePath)
```